# ANDROID : Frame by Frame animation not working?

Tags: android, animation, frame

I am trying to get frame by frame animation but its giving me a force close and I am not sure as to why it is giving me a force close. It all seems alright to me.

Here is my code i hope some one can help?
Thanks in advance.

AnimationTest.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class AnimationTest extends Activity {

AnimationDrawable animation;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    AnimationDrawable animation = new AnimationDrawable();
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.up), 500);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.down), 500);

    animation.setOneShot(false);

    ImageView imageAnim =  (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imageAnim.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);

    // start the animation!
    animation.start();
} 

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:src="@drawable/down"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're starting the animation in the onCreate Method , which will not work because your activity is not displaying yet, use a delayed runnable instead or a clickListener.

you can test the animation using this code:

```
// inside onCreate
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


final AnimationDrawable animation = new AnimationDrawable();
animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.up), 500);
animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.down), 500);

animation.setOneShot(false);

ImageView imageAnim =  (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
imageAnim.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){

public void run(){

animation.start();

}
}, 3000);
```

Please make sure your ImageView has size, and no src is set to see what is going on, in your layout xml file do the following:

```
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
```

and remove src attribute if any

Comment: Just tested and working 100% please see the edit and let's now how did it go

Answer (score 1):

You cant start animation from onCreate method. There is no view yet and activity is not visible. [Read this and change you code a little and it will work.](http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/08/start-animation-in-oncreate-or-onresume-on-android/) I hope so )